# CUDA code fails on Pascal cards (GTX 1080)

Tags: cuda, cublas

I tried running an executable which uses separable compilation on a GTX 1080 today (Compute Capability 6.1 which is not directly supported by CUDA 7.5), and wasn't able to run it, as the first CUDA call fails. I have traced it down to cublas, as this simple program (which doesn't even use cublas)

```
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cstdio>

__global__ void foo()
{
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    void * data = nullptr;
    auto err = cudaMalloc(&data, 256);
    printf("%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    return 0;
}
```

fails (outputs "unknown error") if built using

```
nvcc -dc --gpu-architecture=compute_52 -m64 main.cu -o main.dc.obj
nvcc -dlink --gpu-architecture=compute_52 -m64 -lcublas_device main.dc.obj -o main.obj
link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /LIBPATH:"%CUDA_PATH%\lib\x64" main.obj main.dc.obj cudart_static.lib cudadevrt.lib cublas_device.lib
```

And works (outputs "no error") if built using

```
nvcc -dc --gpu-architecture=compute_52 -m64 main.cu -o main.dc.obj
nvcc -dlink --gpu-architecture=compute_52 -m64 main.dc.obj -o main.obj
link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /LIBPATH:"%CUDA_PATH%\lib\x64" main.obj main.dc.obj cudart_static.lib cudadevrt.lib
```

Even if built using the CUDA 8 release candidate, and `compute_61` instead, it still fails as long as cublas_device.lib is linked.

Comment: I don't understand how your update relates to your question. And I don't believe your interpretation of what is happening is correct. It isn't that there is no PTX, it is that `cuobjdump` doesn't find anything in the output of a device link file which it understands how to disassemble.

Comment: @talonmies I rewrote the question, as the edit apparently only served to confuse, and the initial question was (as you suspected) based on an incorrect assumption. Although, cuobjdump does dump actual PTX, not disassembly. The driver's JIT compiler requires PTX to run CUDA Code on newer architectures.

Comment: The supported method for building codes on windows is to use visual studio.  My suggestion is that you use CUDA 8RC and run the [simpleDevLibCublas sample project](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simpledevlibcublas-gpu-device-api-library-functions--cuda-dynamic-parallelism-).  If it runs correctly in your setup, then study the compilation sequence that is generated in VS carefully, and duplicate that.

Comment: my guess would be that the cublas device library cuda 8 in doesn't have code for compute capability 6.1 devices. i don't have any way of checking that at the moment.

Comment: @RobertCrovella considering the sample states that it supports "SM 3.5, SM 3.7, SM 5.0, SM 5.2", I fear talonmies might be right and that 6.1 just isn't supported at all. I'll check tomorrow at work.

Comment: @Joe The question shows two sets of build commands, one of which fails while the other succeeds. The only difference between the two that I can spot is that one builds from source file `main.cu` the other from source file `main2.cu`. What is the contents of these two source files, and how does it relate to the code included in the question?

Comment: @njuffa neither of them (the build commands) fails for me. It is the result that fails. And the main.cu vs main2.cu was just a mixup during editing (the file is named main2.cu on my computer)

Comment: @njuffa and the difference, as also stated in the text, is that cublas_device is linked or not

Comment: @Joe OK, got it now. I agree with talonmies that the issue may be that the 8.0 RC shipped with a device library that inadvertently is missing `sm_61` support. Since I don't have CUDa 8.0 RC I have no way of verifying or falsifying this hypothesis. If it still fails after going through the due diligence procedure suggested by Robert Crovella, I would suggest filing a bug with NVIDIA.

Comment: ok, so after trying the simpleDevLibCublas sample project which worked for CUDA 8RC but not for 7.5 and some further analysis it has become clear that cublas_device only supports real architectures and not virtual ones. and even in 8RC does not support sm_61, but only sm_60 (which thankfully runs on 6.1 cards as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysis of the [simpleDevLibCublas](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simpledevlibcublas-gpu-device-api-library-functions--cuda-dynamic-parallelism-) example shows that the example is built for a set of real architectures (`sm_xx`), and not for virtual architectures (`compute_xx`), therefore the example in CUDA 7.5 does not run on newer cards. Furthermore, the same example in CUDA 8RC only includes one additional architecture, `sm_60`. [Which is only used by the P100](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus). However, that example does run on 6.1 cards such as the GTX 1080 as well. Support for the `sm_61` architecture is not included in Cublas even in CUDA 8RC.

Therefore, the program will work if built using `--gpu-architecture=sm_60` even if linking `cublas_device`, but will *not* work with `--gpu-architecture=compute_60`, `--gpu-architecture=sm_61` or `--gpu-architecture=compute_61`. Or any `--gpu-architecture=compute_xx` for that matter.